# Sample To Do List in javascript : completed tasks problems

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement("li")
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  var completed_button = document.createElement('input');
  completed_button.type = "button";
  completed_button.value = "Completed";
  newItem.appendChild(completed_button);
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)
}
```

```html
<h1>My To Do list</h1>
<form id="todoForm">
  <input id="todoInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>
</form>
<ul id="todoList">
  <h3>My Tasks</h3>
</ul>
<ul>
  <h3>Completed</h3>
</ul>
```

When I click on the completed button, I want to delete it from **My Tasks** and add it to the **Completed** ones. Can you help?

Comment: You may want to upvote the answer, as it's strange to see an accepted with score 0 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a little with your code and ended up with that snippet:
(I left comments in the code)

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement("li")
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  var completed_button = document.createElement('input');
  completed_button.type = "button";
  completed_button.value = "Completed";
  completed_button.onclick = function() { // Added the onclick function
    clickComplete(this);
  };
  newItem.appendChild(completed_button);
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);
}

// Added this function
function clickComplete(item) {
  document.getElementById("completed").appendChild(item.parentNode);
  item.remove(); // Removes the "completed" button
}
```

```html
<h1>My To Do list</h1>
<form id="todoForm">
  <input id="todoInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>
</form>
<ul id="todoList">
  <h3>My Tasks</h3>
</ul>
<ul id="completed">
  <h3>Completed</h3>
</ul>
```

Feel free to comment me if any modification is to be made in that snippet.

Hope it helps.